# Why does MySQL ignore mutiple dash delimiters in DATE columns?

Tags: mysql, database

Why does the below condition work? Does MySQL convert multiple dashes '---' to a single '-' dash. I tried finding an explanation for this but I couldn't find anything.

```
WHERE DATE(login_at) = '2019---04---30'
```

Can anyone explain to me how this works?

I'm using MySQL Version : 5.7.18

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: MySQL Version  5.7.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL allows a flexibility, by auto-interpreting various delimiters, and converts them to proper date[time] format. It is well explained in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in
>   which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between
>   date parts or time parts. In some cases, this syntax can be deceiving.
>   For example, a value such as '10:11:12' might look like a time value
>   because of the :, but is interpreted as the year '2010-11-12' if used
>   in a date context. The value '10:45:15' is converted to '0000-00-00'
>   because '45' is not a valid month.
>
> The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a
>   fractional seconds part is the decimal point.

So, in your case, MySQL is considering the delimiter as `---`, and thus implicitly converting to `Y-m-d` format.

However, it is always better and **safe** to use the standard **Y-m-d h:i:s** format, to represent a date/datetime value.